# Using xargs to copy directories

Tags: linux, debian, cp, xargs

I'm trying to write a script to copy a set of directories that were created today to another directory.

I'm currently using:

```
find /test/downloads/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -1 -printf '%f\n' | xargs -I '{}' cp -R '{}' /test/uploads/
```

But that gives me an error of:

```
cp: cannot stat 'foo': No such file or directory
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Test your command by doing `find ... | xargs -I xx echo xx /test/uploads/`. In case `xx` is a relative path it may have to be adjusted or prefixed.

Comment: You probably need `%p` rather than `%f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-printf '%f\n'` is a GNU extension that prints the trailing portion of the current file path followed by a newline character. If the file path is `/test/downloads/foo`, it prints `foo\n`.

`xargs` takes that output. Here `foo` contains none of the characters treated specially by `xargs` with `-I{}` (quoting characters, newlines (the only delimiter with `-I`) and leading whitespace, an EOF character with some).

So `{}` is replaced with `foo` in the arguments passed to `cp`. So `cp` ends up being called with `cp`, `-R`, `foo`, `/test/uploads/` as arguments.

So `cp` will look for `foo` in the current working directory, not in `/test/downloads`.

If the file had been called `/test/downloads/-t..`, the command would have been

```
cp -R -t.. /test/uploads/
```

Which tells `cp` to copy `/test/uploads/` to the parent directory of the current working directory.

If the file name had been `/test/downloads/ 'blah'<newline>"blah"`, `cp` would have been called twice as `cp -R blah /test/uploads/`.

So you have two problems:

1. With `%f`, you're stripping the leading directory components to the file
2. You're using `xargs` which cannot be used reliably on the output of `find` (other than with the non-standard `-r` and `-0` options to process NUL-delimited records).

One could also add that you're calling `cp` for each directory even though `cp` is well capable of copying more than one file at a time.

Here, standardly, that should be:

```
find /test/downloads/. ! -name . -prune -type d -mtime -1 -exec sh -c '
  exec cp -R "$@" /test/uploads/' sh {} +
```

Which with GNU implementations of those utilities (as found by default in your Debian system) can be simplified to:

```
find /test/downloads/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime -1 \
  -exec cp -Rt /test/uploads/ {} +
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation helped immensely!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a file named "`foo bar`".

A better way would be to replace from your `-printf ...` to the end with:

```
-print0 | xargs -0 -r cp -t /Test/Uploads
```

Read `man find xargs cp`.