# Using unix, copy, relocate and rename files from nested directories to dir with name derived from the path

Tags: xargs

I have a file.txt with a list of 100 files and their paths. Here are the first 3 entries:

```
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/lb/MAP-9-003/c44caf4c-cab7-4749-9940-a74a66bceec3/c44caf4c-cab7-4749-9940-a74a66bceec3.bam
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/lb/MAP-9-007/3e5a10e0-3928-40c5-8dfb-9bbe9d5e0105/3e5a10e0-3928-40c5-8dfb-9bbe9d5e0105.bam
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/lb/MAP-9-013/e230fce2-8f54-4d30-bb75-38d11a438f68/e230fce2-8f54-4d30-bb75-38d11a438f68.bam
```

I want to cp these files, rename the new files and put them in another dir & path, where the new dir name is the dir in the 8th level of the old path, and the new file name = new dir name + file extension. The new dir location also changes. I would get the new files sorted like this:

```
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/map/MAP-9-003/MAP-9-003.bam #(old c44caf4c-cab7-4749-9940-a74a66bceec3.bam)
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/map/MAP-9-007/MAP-9-007.bam #(old 3e5a10e0-3928-40c5-8dfb-9bbe9d5e0105.bam)
/project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/map/MAP-9-013/MAP-9-013.bam #(old e230fce2-8f54-4d30-bb75-38d11a438f68.bam)
```

I found these posts:
[Using xargs to copy directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627535/using-xargs-to-copy-directories) and
[Copy files with certain extension from many nested sub-directories to a single directory and append to each copied file the name of the directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459840/copy-files-with-certain-extension-from-many-nested-sub-directories-to-a-single-d)

doing related tasks but I am unable to do my specific task

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to indicate what you already tried, and where you faced specific problems. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you alread know won't work, or that rely on tools you don't have installed.

Answer (score 1):

I let you copy the files where you want. To rename, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.

```
mkdir -p ./project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/map
rename -n 's@(project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/)lb/(MAP-.*?)/.*/.*.bam@$1map/$2.bam@' ./project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/lb/MAP-9-0*/*/*.bam
# rm -rf ./project/msun/USERS/me/czi/data/lb/MAP*
```

Comment: Thank you @Gilles Quénot ! Will the .bam files be renamed in the original folder or in the new folder? I'd like them to be renamed only in the new folder, please.

Comment: In the new one. The `-n` permit to test without doing for real as explained, to renane for real, remove `-n` switch. With `-n` you have just the output of what will be renamed in _test mode_.

Comment: Thank you @Gilles. Apparently rename needs more arguments, with or without -n:

    rename: not enough arguments
    Try 'rename --help' for more information.

Comment: What is the output of `rename --version` ?

Comment: it is: rename from util-linux 2.32.1

Comment: Which OS do you run?

Comment: I am running it in a remote server:

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:cxx-4.1-amd64:cxx-4.1-noarch:desktop-4.1-amd64:desktop-4.1-noarch:languages-4.1-amd64:languages-4.1-noarch:printing-4.1-amd64:printing-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterprise
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.4 (Ootpa)
Release: 8.4
Codename: Ootpa

Comment: `cpan File::Rename` Then search `file-rename`

Comment: $ cpan File::Rename
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
 LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Loading internal null logger. Install Log::Log4perl for logging messages
Reading '/home/me/.cpan/Metadata'
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20181130)
File::Rename is up to date (2.01).

$ file-rename
bash: file-rename: command not found...

Comment: `find ~ -name 'file-rename*'` or `dnf install prename`

Comment: If I replace "rename -n" by find ~ -name 'file-rename*' or "dnf install prename", then it doesn't work. Maybe I should look for a unix-only solution